# Keeping links in an iframe in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

How does one keep all redirects from an iframe within the iframe? Sort of like a browser within the page. I've seen it done many times on translating sites, vpn sites, security sites, etc.

**For Clarification:** http://bit.ly/1m8EF4e
<-- Google translation of a wikipedia page. Notice how redirects are still within the iFrame of the translator.

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="(src)" target="_self">` for opening the link in a same iframe
for new tab change the `targer` value to `_blank`

Comment: Don't I need to edit the page's <a> elements? And what about if a redirect is performed via jQuery/Javascript or any other method? For example, a search.